# First program: javascript countdown timer

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to code my own timer from scratch. Complete noob here. I know there's a good amount of tutorials out there about building a timer, but from experience, whenever I use examples I don't really learn. Here's the code I come up with:

```
<p id="myTimer">Blank Text</p>

var timer = 60;

function updatePLEASE() {
    timer--;
}

while (timer > 0){
    console.log(timer);
    document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML = timer;
    setTimeout(updatePLEASE(), 1000); /* replicate wait 1 second */
}
```

When it runs, it shows "1". I thought it was returning a boolean value at first until I added the console.log and saw that the script does thankfully countdown from 60 down to 1. But, the script seems to only use setTimeout once.

Why doesn't the script wait 1000 ms before running the loop again? Or better question: Am I using the setTimeout function correctly?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: `setTimeout()` by definition only runs *once*.

Comment: My understanding is that, despite the loop running 60 times, the setTimeout 1000ms is only used once. I tried moving setTimeout a bunch of places but get the same results.

Comment: Likley you set so many "timeout" handlers inside that loop, that when they all fire, the global you have is reduced to 1, and very quickly after the initial delay of one second.

Comment: Here is one example how to do it https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/create-countdown-timer-using-javascript/amp/

Comment: @Lemmy If OP knew, he wouldn't ask here. And I don't think this is something you can easily understand as being completely new to it. @OP Your `setTimeout()` function works as it should. The problem is your `while()` loop. It doesn't depend on your timeout function. So while the timeout function is waiting, the while loop just finishes near instantly. I suggest you have a look at [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) instead. And you'll no longer need the while loop.

Comment: @icecub Thanks. I initially started with 'setInterval()' and already got a new script using that working to my design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout` take function name and it will `if` not `while` and change the text within `function`.

```js
var timer = 60;

function updatePLEASE() {
    timer--;
    if (timer > 0){
    //console.log(timer);
    document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML = timer;
    setTimeout(updatePLEASE, 1000); /* replicate wait 1 second */
}
}
updatePLEASE();
```

```html
<p id="myTimer">Blank Text</p>
```

Comment: Best answer; reflects OP's existing code and is succinct

Comment: Agreed @GetSet, I much prefer modifications to my code, even if it is poorly written. These types of answers make the most sense to me. Thanks, Mohammad.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout` is async. Therefor you need something that will wait for that async operation to end.

You can do it in 2 ways:

#### 1. wrap it with a "recursive" function.

So after 1 sec you call this function again and again until 0.

```js
let timer = 60;

function updatePLEASE() {
  timer--;
}

function countDownTimer() {
  if (timer > 0) {
    console.log(timer);
    document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML = timer;
    updatePLEASE();
    setTimeout(countDownTimer, 1000); /* replicate wait 1 second */
  }
}

countDownTimer();
```

```html
<p id="myTimer">Blank Text</p>
```

#### 2. Use `await` and `Promise`:

```js
let timer = 60;

function updatePLEASE() {
  timer--;
}

async function countDownTimer() {
  while (timer > 0) {
    console.log(timer);
    document.getElementById("myTimer").innerHTML = timer;
    await new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
        updatePLEASE();
        resolve();
      }, 1000));

  }
}

countDownTimer();
```

```html
<p id="myTimer">Blank Text</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems with the code:

1) The while loop completes before any setTimeout is run. Just so you know: setTimeout is asynchronous. Maybe you should do some reading about sync vs async code in Javascript.

2) The first param of setTimeout is a function. You pass the result of the function.

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` accept `function` name only or variable function, however by mistake u exciting it.

```
setTimeout(updatePLEASE(), 1000);
```

**Correct:**

```
setTimeout(updatePLEASE, 1000);
```

> Note: Code is wrong. it will run while loop without the wait of `setTimeout`. Because setTimeout runs asynchronously in `event-loop`.

**More:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop

You can delay using `async-await`. but example is little complex. I will recommend use recursion for this case.

```js
var timer = 60;
const delay = (fn) =>
  new Promise((r) => {
    fn();
    setTimeout(r, 1000);
  });
function updatePLEASE() {
  timer--;
}
async function main() {
  while (timer > 0) {
    // delay 1 sec
    console.log(timer)
    await delay(updatePLEASE);
  }
}
main();
```